# Quarkus code hangs after calling close() on JMS session

Tags: java, jms, quarkus, activemq-artemis

Hi I have the following Java 11 Quarkus project

simple endpoint

```java
package org.acme.jms;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/jms")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class JMSEndpoint {

  @Inject
  JMSProducer producer;

  @POST
  public Response sendMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("recieved request");
    producer.sendMessage(message);

    return Response.status(201).build();
  }
}
```

I then have a JMS producer like so

```java
package org.acme.jms;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@ApplicationScoped
public class JMSProducer {

  @Inject
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  public ResponseBuilder sendMessage(String message) {
    try (
      JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE
      )
    ) {
      context.createProducer().send(context.createQueue("test123"), message);
      System.out.println("hello");
      return Response.status(201);
    } catch (JMSRuntimeException ex) {
      // handle exception (details omitted)
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

When i `POST http://localhost:9999/jms` with the data `{"message":"Hello!"}` I see in the logs that

```bash
2023-02-10 18:02:54,411 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionImpl] (executor-thread-0) Calling close on session ClientSessionImpl [name=c286799e-a964-11ed-8c7d-00155d72b785, username=quarkus, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@7e4bc0a6, metaData=()]@17bdcc0a
Hello!
```

then it gets stuck here for about 20-30 seconds and finally it manages to close the connection and return 200 to postman

```bash
2023-02-10 18:03:24,412 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionImpl] (executor-thread-0) calling cleanup on ClientSessionImpl [name=c286799e-a964-11ed-8c7d-00155d72b785, username=quarkus, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@7e4bc0a6, metaData=()]@17bdcc0a
2023-02-10 18:03:24,414 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionImpl] (executor-thread-0) Calling close on session ClientSessionImpl [name=c285411d-a964-11ed-8c7d-00155d72b785, username=quarkus, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@7e4bc0a6, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@20b6a6bb
2023-02-10 18:03:24,417 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionImpl] (executor-thread-0) calling cleanup on ClientSessionImpl [name=c285411d-a964-11ed-8c7d-00155d72b785, username=quarkus, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@7e4bc0a6, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@20b6a6bb
2023-02-10 18:03:24,419 DEBUG [org.apa.act.art.cor.cli.imp.ClientSessionImpl] (executor-thread-0) Session was already closed, giving up now, this=ClientSessionImpl [name=c285411d-a964-11ed-8c7d-00155d72b785, username=quarkus, closed=true, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@7e4bc0a6, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@20b6a6bb
```

What i expect to happen is that that the client closes the connection directly and returns the status to postman. Why does it take 30 seconds?  I have no idea how to solve this issue I've tried everything it feels like and no success.

My pom.xml for version

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms-quickstart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.12.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <quarkus-artemis.version>1.2.0</quarkus-artemis.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkiverse.artemis</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-artemis-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-artemis.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkiverse.artemis</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-artemis-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: It's not clear why `close()` is taking so long. Do you have any thread dumps during the delay which might shed light on what the client code is doing during this time?

Comment: It's worth noting that unless the `ConnectionFactory` you're injecting is _pooled_ then you're employing a well-known anti-pattern where you create & close a `JMSContext` for _every_ message you send. Is your `ConnectionFactory` pooled?

Comment: @JustinBertram it is not pooled. i assumed you would close the connection after recieving a message. if that's not the case should a non pooled connection be kept open? I thought that would waste resources maintaining a connection. Would a pooled connection be a better option for the usecase demonstrated above?

Comment: If you don't use a pooled `ConnectionFactory` implementation (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) then you should definitely maintain an open `JMSContext` (or `Connection`) to be used for every call. Generally speaking, creating and closing a `JMSContext` (or `Connection`) for every message sent or received is _way_ more wasteful than simply keeping one open. It's hard to say if a pool would be better as I don't have all the details of your use-case. You should try both and see which works better for you.

Comment: @JustinBertram okej thank you if you can provide any link that talks about keeping it open that would great and i would accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why `close()` is taking so long. You'd need to gather thread dumps during the delay in order to shed light on what the client code is doing during this time.

Aside from that, it's worth noting that you're employing a well-known anti-pattern where you create & close a `JMSContext` for *every* message you send. This anti-pattern is noted in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tuning.html#avoiding-anti-patterns). To deal with this anti-pattern you can use a pooled `ConnectionFactory` implementation (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms)) or simply maintain an open `JMSContext` (or `Connection`) to be used for every call. Generally speaking, creating and closing a `JMSContext` (or `Connection`) for every message sent and/or received is way more wasteful than simply keeping one open. It's hard to say if a pool would be better as I don't have all the details of your use-case. You should try both and see which works better for you.